# Set session variables in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In vanilla PHP, I can set a session variable using the below code;

```
$_SESSION['blog'] = array(
    "email" => $_POST['email'],
    "password" => $password,
    "firstname" => $row ['firstName'],
    "lastname" => $row ['lastName'],
    "id" => $row ['id']
);
```

How can I do the same in `laravel`.
FYI I'm not talking about the default session name eg `PHPSESSID` or `laravel_session`. I have multiple session variables for parts of my site such as `web`, `blog`, 'careers' and I name them just like the code above and able to check and access them individually. So one user can have all three sessions variables at the same time but for different sections of the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way you could do it:

```
$vars = [
    "email" => $email,
    "password" => $password,
    "firstname" => $row['firstName'],
    "lastname" => $row['lastName'],
    "id" => $row['id']
];

session()->put('blog', $vars);
```

[Laravel Docs - Session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session)

**Update:** To check existence of a session variable:

```
session()->has('blog'); // bool
```

**Update:** To get an element contained in the session variable 'blog'

```
session('blog.id'); // using the dot notation
```

Comment: How can I check if the session exists? Check if `blog` session exists

Comment: @moh.ABK I updated the answer to add a check for the existence of a session variable.

Comment: @moh.ABK  'blog' is just a session variable set on the session, it is not its own SESSION or anything like that. It is also not a session name, it is a session variable.

Comment: so when I set a session with variable `blog` which then contains an array, how can I get a specific attribute of the array like `$_SESSION['blog']['email']` in normal `php`

Comment: @moh.ABK no prob my friend, answer has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Place the array in a variable
$session_array = array(
                "email" => $_POST['email'],
                "password" => $password,
                "firstname" => $row ['firstName'],
                "lastname" => $row ['lastName'],
                "id" => $row ['id']
                );


//Place that $session_array inside the session using \Session::put('key','value')
\Session::put('blog',$session_array);

// To access the session value
print_r(\Session::get('blog'));
```